# Return by reference PHP

Tags: php

In documentation i see how we set 2 `&`, why?

And can say me please what difference beetween

*this 1:*

```
function &func()
{
     static $static = 0;
     $static++;
     return $static;
}
$var1 = func();
echo "var1:", $var1; // 1
```

and *this 2:*

```
function func()
{
     static $static = 0;
     $static++;
     return $static;
}
$var1 = func();
echo "var1:", $var1; // 1
```

**Or alternative variant**

*this 1:*

```
function &func()
{
     static $static = 0;
     $static++;
     return $static;
}
$var1 = &func();
echo "var1:", $var1; // 1
```

and *this 2:*

```
function func()
{
     static $static = 0;
     $static++;
     return $static;
}
$var1 = &func();
echo "var1:", $var1; // 1
```

Answer (score 1):

There is only a difference between the first `this 2` and the second `this 1`. All others are wrongly tried `return by reference`.

The second  `this 2` even throws a PHP notice (`Notice: Only variables should be assigned by reference in ... on line ...`).

The difference is that the first `this 2` returns by value while the second `this 1` returns by reference. Since it is a reference, the variable can be changed outside the function.

```
function &func()
{
     static $static = 0;
     $static++;
     return $static;
}
$var1 = &func();
echo "var1:", $var1; // 1
$var1 = 10;
$var1 = &func();
echo "\nvar1:", $var1; // 11
```

https://3v4l.org/uJHSF

evals for all snippets (with second function call):
1st this 1: https://3v4l.org/p6erT
1st this 2: https://3v4l.org/9OcaC
2nd this 1: https://3v4l.org/uJHSF
2nd this 2: https://3v4l.org/qJ3qO

See also the PHP manual: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php

Comment: There is no real difference in your example since you just output the variables. The difference lays into how something gets returned. You use references if you have an explicit use. Printing something does not require a reference and you shouldn't use references for that.

Comment: so what difference beetween `1st this 1` and `1st this 2`, or no difference here?

Comment: All except `2nd this 1` return by value. Take a look at the eval snippets in my answer. Also read the PHP manual page, it contains valuable informations.